# Counting points in a scratch layer polygon using QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, count

I'm using QGIS 3 and I am trying to count the points in a scratch layer polygon. When I use the count points in a polygon tool it says there are no points in my polygon which is untrue.

I figured the polygon being a scratch layer could be the issue. I get an error message when trying to create the polygon in a shapefile. So i'm not sure how to fix that either.

[image]

Comment: Based on the screenshot, the polygon layer is in edit mode. Have you tried exiting editing mode, and computing intersections afterwards?

Comment: I've just tried to re-do it after taking it out of edit mode still didn't work. Is computing intersections a different tool to count points in a polygon?

Comment: The scratch layer should not be a problem. But both layers must be in the same CRS. Have your points and polygon layers the same CRS?

Comment: You may need to convert a point layer from a multipoint to a point layer ...

Comment: All the layers are in the same CRS. I have tried changing it to a single point layer through the multipart to single parts tool in the vector drop down its still coming up as 0 for the feature count.

Comment: What "error message when trying to create the polygon in a shapefile" do you get?